# Lookup with default broken in Dataset

Tags: dataset, associations

Given an `Association`,

```
data = <|"1" -> <|"A" -> 10, "B" -> 20|>, 
  "2" -> <|"C" -> 30, "B" -> 40|>|>
```

`Lookup` works w/ default:

```
 data // Map[Lookup[#, "A", 0] &]
```

> <|"1" -> 10, "2" -> 0|>

But not in `Dataset` (output is the `FullForm`)

```
data // Dataset // Query[All, Lookup[#, "A", 0] &]
```

> Failure[Dataset,Association[RuleDelayed["MessageTemplate",MessageName[Dataset,"invalid"]],Rule["MessageParameters",Association[Rule["Head",Lookup],Rule["Arguments",List[Assoc[Atom[String],Atom[Integer],2],"A",0]],Rule["Symbol",Lookup]]]]]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem occurs because the three-argument form of `Lookup` is not recognized by the type inferencing performed by `Dataset`.  One work-around is to use `Query` directly, bypassing the type inferencing:

```
data // Query[All, Lookup[#, "A", 0]&]
(* <| "1" -> 10, "2" -> 0 |> *)
```

Another (nasty) work-around is to "hide" the symbol `Lookup` from the type inferencer by expressing it instead as `Lookup&[]`:

```
data // Dataset // Query[All, Lookup&[][#, "A", 0]&]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

---

**Discussion (current as of version 10.1)**

A `Dataset` query starts by attempting to infer the types of its arguments for various purposes.  The responsible function is `` TypeSystem`TypeApply ``.  Notionally, this function can infer the type of any valid Wolfram expression.  I say "notionally" because I am not sure whether it is intended to be able to handle all expressions, or only a query-friendly subset.

In any event, `TypeApply` has special handling for certain operators.  We can see at least some of those operators by evaluating this expression:

```
{TypeSystem`$Signatures, TypeSystem`$SubSignatures} // Query[Flatten /* Sort, Keys]

(* {AllTrue,AnyTrue,Append,...,Lookup,...,Values,Variance,VectorQ,Vectors} *)
```

`Lookup` is one of the special operators.  We can see which forms of `Lookup` are accepted by evaluating:

```
printSignatures[s_Symbol] :=
  Block[{$ContextPath = {"TypeSystem`","TypeSystem`ZSignatures`PackagePrivate`"} ~Join~
                        $ContextPath }
  , Print @ Column @ TypeSystem`$Signatures[s][[All, 1]]
  ]

printSignatures[Lookup]
  (*
    {s_Struct, keys:{__String}}
    {Vector[Assoc[k_,v_,_],m_], Vector[k_,n_]}
    {Assoc[k_,v_,_], Vector[k_,n_]}
    {Assoc[k_,v_,_], k_}
    {Vector[Assoc[k_,v_,_],m_], k_}
    {s_Struct, key_String}
    {Vector[s_Struct,n_], key_}
  *)
```

We can see that all of these signatures accept only two arguments.  The three-argument form is not accepted.  This is the origin of the error message that we get:

> Expression of the form Lookup[Association[(_String -> _Integer)..], "A", 0] cannot be evaluated.

The phrase *cannot be evaluated* in this case actually means *cannot be have its type inferred by `TypeApply`*.

All of this talk of signatures is only relevant for the recognized operators.  Unrecognized operators receive only light treatment, and often end up with a generic type annotation.

The exhibited expression works in versions 10.0.1, but fails in versions 10.0.2 and 10.1.  The reason is that starting with 10.0.2, `TypeApply` started looking into `Function` expressions.  Prior to 10.0.2, the `Lookup[...]&` expression would have been treated as an unrecognized function and would be passed through without signature analysis.  But now that `Function` is transparent, the signature restriction is causing difficulties.

We can see how the nasty work-around expression `Lookup&[]` works:  it is treated by `TypeApply` as an unknown operator.  `TypeApply` does not (presently) evaluate `Function` expression heads before performing signature analysis.  This could change at any time.

It is not clear to me whether this restriction of `Lookup` to two arguments is  intentional or an oversight.  The inferred type of three-argument `Lookup` applied to an `Association` would need to be the least supertype containing the third argument type and the association value type.

Almost none of this discussion comes from official WRI documentation.  Take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks for writing these detailed reports.

Comment: Sometimes your first solution `data // Query[All, Lookup[#, "A", 0]&]` doesn't work, whereas `Lookup&[]` does when used directly `data[All, Lookup &[][#, keys, 0] &]` or as a separate `Query`.

Comment: @alancalvitti I'd be interested to know about a case where the first solution fails for a non-dataset object since that would be an entirely different class of problem.  If the details are lengthy, it might be best to discuss it in chat rather than the comments here.

Comment: Let me clarify, I meant in the context of `Dataset`. Nevertheless, 1st case doesn't work while the 2nd does - and thanks for the &[] syntax - new to me.

Comment: @alancalvitti @WReach This is fixed in 10.2. You can now write `TypeSystem`Signatures[Lookup]` and you'll see a nice table of what the rules are.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really an answer, but it can't be written as comment.

I'm running V10.1 on OS X. I get the same results, so I also think it's a bug. I note the problem seems to be the presence of the 3rd argument, even if it not used.

```
data = <|"1" -> <|"A" -> 10, "B" -> 20|>, "2" -> <|"C" -> 30, "B" -> 40|>|>;
ds = Dataset[data]
```

[image: dataset]

```
ds[All, Lookup[#, "B"] &]
```

[image: ok-lookup]

```
ds[All, Lookup[#, "B", 0] &]
```

[image: bad-lookup]