# Dataset breaks multi-character StringSplit

Tags: string-manipulation, dataset

Given

```
ds = Dataset[{"a b", "c-d"} ]
```

multi-character `StringSplit` is broken with `Dataset` (10.1 regression?)

```
ds[All, StringSplit[#, {" ", "-"}] &]
```

[image]

though single split charaters works:

```
ds[All, StringSplit[#, " "] &] // Normal
```

> {{"a", "b"}, {"c-d"}}

As does plain non-Dataset version of multi-char of course (same output as above)

```
ds // Normal // Map[StringSplit[#, {" ", "-"}] &]
```

Comment: Really 10.2? Or 10.0.2?

Comment: My bad, 10.1, edited.

Comment: Same for me with v10.1.0 (OSX) but this will work : `ds[All, StringSplit[#, " " | "-"] &]` ...

Comment: @SquareOne Confirmed in 10.1.0 under Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is due to the same type-inferencing problem described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85363/142).

Using `printSignatures` from the referenced answer, we can see that the type inferencer will only accept a single string as the second argument, not a list:

```
printSignatures[StringSplit]
  (*
    {Vector[Atom[String], n_]}
    {Atom[String]}
    {Atom[String], Atom[String]}
    {Vector[Atom[String], n_], Atom[String]}
  *)
```

This list of valid signatures will only accept a single string as the second argument.

The referenced answer shows how to dodge the type-inferencer.  We can use similar work-arounds here:  either by using `Query` directly on the raw data...

```
ds // Normal // Query[Dataset, StringSplit[#, {" ", "-"}] &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

... or by disguising the `StringSplit` operator:

```
ds[All, StringSplit&[][#, {" ", "-"}] &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Notice how the second work-around loses useful type information in this case, causing the dataset visualization to fall back to a cruder form.  We can restore the missing type information by inserting a terminal `Dataset` ascending operator into the query:

```
ds[Dataset, StringSplit&[][#, {" ", "-"}] &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This last operation causes the proper type information to be deduced from the final output data (using `` TypeSystem`DeduceType ``), restoring the proper visualization.

Comment: This is fixed in 10.2. P.S. Because StringSplit works on lists of strings, `ds[StringSplit[#, " "] &]` will work, too. as will  just `ds[StringSplit]` (if you're splitting on whitespace, that is).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a problem of your specific version. Im running 10.0.1.0 MacOS and it works just fine.

[image]