# Explaining error when using Part inside Module in Dataset

Tags: warning-messages, dataset, scoping

I have a vague recollection of seen an explanation for this, but I can not find it, so it may be a false memory. Will delete if duplicated.

Let `ds` be a simple [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html)

```
ds = Dataset@Table[
   <|"index" -> i, "data" -> RandomReal[1, 4]|>
   , {i, 3}]
```

This does NOT work (error message:  k is not a valid part specification, Tag: dataset)

```
ds[All, Module[{k = 2, l}, l = #data[[k]]; <|#, "part2" -> l|>] &]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

But these very similar expression do work fine

```
ds[All, Module[{k = 1, l}, <|#, "part2" -> #data[[k + 1]]|>] &] (* Example 1 *)

ds[All, <|#, "part2" -> Module[{k = 2, l}, l = #data[[k]]]|> &] (* Example 2 *)

ds[All, Module[{k = 1, l},l = Extract[#data, {k + 1}]; <|#, "part2" -> l|>] &] (* Example 3 *)
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Using [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) instead of [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) gives the same result.

**Where does this error come from?**

Using Mathematica 11.0.1 on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: @gwr  sorry, I don't see your point. That function acting at that data should work, for example, `Block[{k = 2, l}, l = #data[[k]]; <|#, "part2" -> l|>] & /@ Normal@ds` works too.

Comment: @gwr Thanks for your comments, but the problem is not to find something that works, I offered myself three examples that do work. The question was *Where does this error come from?*

Comment: Looking at what is going on with trace I note some rather complex evaluation with `HoldComplete` ... and `Dataset`-validity checking going on. Indeed beats me and for all this I usually always use `Association`and lists of them to do a `Query` saving `Dataset` only for display purposes. Good luck then.

Comment: So the answer is the `Hold` inside the `Dataset` handling machinery. Using `#data[[2]]` will work, but the `k` remains a symbol as far as I can see.

Comment: Related: [(87360)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87360/764)

Comment: similar, alas: [(85114)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85114/142), [(85270)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85270/142), [(88503)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88503/142), [(126010)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126010/142), [(130330)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130330/142), [(137129)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137129/142)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cause**

The problem is caused by a type-inferencing failure.  When presented with a complex expression, the type inferencer will sometimes give up and tag the expression as being of type `UnknownType`.  But at other times, the inferencer will fail outright.  Expressions of the form `<|#, ... |>` or `Extract[...]` are identified as `UnknownType`.  In constrast, expressions like `expr[[k]]` fall into the "failure" category when `k` is a symbol.

The expression that fails contains a "naked" reference to `#data[[k]]`.  In working examples #1 and #2, the problematic part reference is contained within an outer expression `<|#, ... |>` -- so the type inferencer gives up (yielding `UnknownType`) before the part reference can fail.  Working example #3 omits the `Part` reference altogether and uses `Extract` instead (which also yields `UnknownType`).

**Work-around**

The usual work-around for `Dataset` type system failures applies... dodge the type system by using `Query` on the raw data and wrapping `Dataset` around the result for visualization:

```
ds //
  Normal //
  Query[All, Module[{k=2, l}, l=#data[[k]]; <|#, "part2"->l|>]&] //
  Dataset
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

**Analysis**

*current as of Mathematica v11.1.0*

As part of the operation of a `Dataset` query, the system first performs some type checks to do some "sanity checks".  In the case at hand, these checks fail outright:

```
ds[All, Module[{k = 2, l}, l = #data[[k]]; <|#, "part2" -> l|>] &]
(* Failure[...] *)
```

We can reduce this to a smaller example:

```
ds[All, Module[{k = 1}, #data[[k]]] &]
(* Failure[...] *)
```

Or even:

```
Dataset[{0}][Module[{k = 1}, #[[k]]] &]
(* Failure[...] *)
```

The cause is a failure of the type-inferencing function `TypeApply`:

```
Needs["TypeSystem`"]

TypeApply[{0}[[k]]&, {}]
(* FailureType[{Part, "Spec"}, <|"Type" -> Tuple[{Atom[Integer]}], "Part" -> k|>] *)
```

The full sequence of events looks like this:

[image: stack excerpt]

The component that is letting us down is `TypePart`.  It can handle indices that are scalars, vectors or types:

```
TypePart[Tuple[{Atom[Integer]}], 1]
(* Atom[Integer] *)

TypePart[Tuple[{Atom[Integer]}], {1, 1}]
(* Tuple[{Atom[Integer], Atom[Integer]}] *)

TypePart[Tuple[{Atom[Integer]}],Atom[Integer]]
(* AnyType *)
```

But it fails outright when presented with a symbol:

```
TypePart[Tuple[{Atom[Integer]}], k]
(* FailureType[...] *)
```

I think it is arguable that this is a bug... a symbolic index should probably result in `AnyType` under the assumption that it will evaluate to a valid index at run time.

The working examples (1, 2, and 3) all "hide" the problematic part reference from the type inferencer by surrounding it by a troublesome, but not failing,  outer expression:

```
TypeApply[<|#, "a" -> #a[[k]]|> &, DeduceType /@ {<|"a" -> {1, 2}|>}]
(* UnknownType *)

TypeApply[Extract[#a, {k + 1}] &, DeduceType /@ {<|"a" -> {1, 2}|>}]
(* UnknownType *)
```

The type inferencer is still confused, returning `UnknownType`, but at least it does not fail outright.  The vague type information has no bearing upon the query evaluation process so we get the expected results.  (`UnknownType` has been known to cause `Dataset` rendering issues from time-to-time.)

The `Dataset` type system tends to be (overly?) conservative when type-checking, but `Query` does no type-checking at all.  So `Query` remains a viable work-around for these kinds of errors.