# Apply a function over Dataset as if it's an Association

Tags: dataset, associations

Take a list of `Associations`. Using the `Dataset` function, this can be converted to a structured dataset.

```
associationList={
<|"a"->1,"b"->"x","c"->9|>,
<|"a"->2,"b"->"y","c"->8|>,
<|"a"->3,"b"->"z","c"->7|>}
dataset=Dataset[associationList]
```

[image]

Consider these three functions which can perform simple operations on each association.

```
function1=Function[{input},input[[{"c","b"}]]];
function2=Function[{input},Keys[input]];
function3=Function[{input},input[[Keys[input]]]];
```

When the first function is applied, it `Takes` elements based on *hard-coded* `Keys`.

```
dataset[All,function1]
Map[function1,associationList]
```

[image]

When the second function is applied, it programmatically gives all `Keys`.

```
dataset[All,function2]
Map[function2,associationList]
```

[image]

However, when the final function is applied, something peculiar occurs. For the list of `Associations`, it evaluates the `Keys` and uses these to `Take` elements, as I expected. For the `Dataset`, it gives an error.

```
dataset[All,function3]
Map[function3,associationList]
```

[image]

I initially assumed a `Dataset` was just a wrapper for a list of (nested) `Associations`. And that `dataset[All, func]` would *loop* over all internal `Associations` and apply `func`, similar to `Map`. This idea was too naive.

Can someone explain *why* the current behaviour makes sense?

Note that I am *not* looking for a work-around to apply `function3` to my `Dataset`. I know I can obtain the desired answer in multiple ways. I am trying to *understand* the connection between `Associations` and `Dataset`.

Comment: I have learned that `Needs["Dataset"]`, `Needs["TypeSystem"]` and `GetType[dataset]` gives `Struct[{"a", "b", "c"}, {Atom[Integer], Atom[String], Atom[Integer]}]`.

Comment: I think you are on the write track.  `Dataset` isn't just a wrapper for `Associations` but rather includes information on the types of data contained within.  It is interesting to note at the WTC this year, we were told that this extra information causes more problems than it solves and is being done away with.  In fact, lots of major changes are coming to `Dataset`.  FYI, you can see the structure in your example above by using `InputForm[dataset]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in the type deduction system of `Dataset`. In principle, your example should work as you expect. The problem is that when given a query, `Dataset` attempts to predict the type of the result before executing the query. Now in principle, this should happen silently in the background without you seeing anything. In your case, something like the following happens:

- The query is `All, Function[{input}, …]` (note how `function3` has been evaluated)
- The `All` simply causes the inner function to be mapped, therefore the outer list stays a list (a `` TypeSystem`Vector[…, 3] `` to be precise)
- Now it tries to figure out what `Function[{input}, ...]` returns when applied to a `` TypeSystem`Struct[{"a", "b", "c"}, …] ``.

  - `Dataset` "knows" how to handle pure functions (i.e. `Function[…]`), so it tries to deduce the resulting data type.
  - It does so by first inserting the type (i.e. `` TypeSystem`Struct[…] ``) into the body of the function.
  - At this point, it tries to deduce the resulting type of `` TypeSystem`Struct[…][[Keys[TypeSystem`Struct[…]]]] ``
  - The deduction of expressions of the form `…[[…]]` with symbolic indices is unfortunately broken, resulting in the error message you are seeing. (See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140541/explaining-error-when-using-part-inside-module-in-dataset?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more information)

The are numerous work-arounds for this (see for example the post linked above for some), you can for example hide the pure function behind a symbol with down-values (the type system does not attempt to deduce the type in this case):

```
function3b[arg_] := function3@arg

dataset[All, function3b]
Map[function3, associationList]
```

[image]