# Allocate amount A according to the distribution of amount B

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, gathering

I have a cost that varies by category and date.  I also have the counts of each item type within each category and date.  I want to distribute the cost to each of the item types.  I'm trying to use `GroupBy`, and `Normalize` to get the percentage distribution by item type.  My plan is to then multiply these percentages by the cost for each category and date.

```
x1 = {
     <|"cat" -> "a", "type" -> "abc1", "date" -> {2013, 1}, "count" -> 10|>,
     <|"cat" -> "a", "type" -> "abc2", "date" -> {2013, 1}, "count" -> 20|>,
     <|"cat" -> "a", "type" -> "abc3", "date" -> {2013, 1}, "count" -> 30|>,
     <|"cat" -> "a", "type" -> "abc1", "date" -> {2014, 1}, "count" -> 40|>,
     <|"cat" -> "a", "type" -> "abc2", "date" -> {2014, 1}, "count" -> 50|>,
     <|"cat" -> "a", "type" -> "abc1", "date" -> {2015, 1}, "count" -> 13|>,
     <|"cat" -> "b", "type" -> "abc1", "date" -> {2013, 1}, "count" -> 60|>,
     <|"cat" -> "b", "type" -> "abc1", "date" -> {2014, 1}, "count" -> 70|>,
     <|"cat" -> "b", "type" -> "abc2", "date" -> {2013, 1}, "count" -> 75|>
     };
x2 = GroupBy[x1, {#cat, #date} &, Normalize[#, Total] &]
```

This results in the following:

```
<|{"a", {2013, 1}} -> 
 {<|"cat" -> 1/3, "type" -> ("abc1")/("abc1" + "abc2" + "abc3"), "date" -> {1/3, 1/3}, "count" -> 1/6|>, 
  <|"cat" -> 1/3, "type" -> ("abc2")/("abc1" + "abc2" + "abc3"), "date" -> {1/3, 1/3}, "count" -> 1/3|>, 
  <|"cat" -> 1/3, "type" -> ("abc3")/("abc1" + "abc2" + "abc3"), "date" -> {1/3, 1/3}, "count" -> 1/2|>}, 
 {"a", {2014, 1}} -> 
 {<|"cat" -> 1/2, "type" -> ("abc1")/("abc1" + "abc2"), "date" -> {1/2, 1/2}, "count" -> 4/9|>, 
  <|"cat" -> 1/2, "type" -> ("abc2")/("abc1" + "abc2"), "date" -> {1/2, 1/2}, "count" -> 5/9|>},
 {"a", {2015, 1}} -> 
 {<|"cat" -> 1, "type" -> 1, "date" -> {1, 1}, "count" -> 1|>}, 
 {"b", {2013, 1}} -> 
 {<|"cat" -> 1/2, "type" -> ("abc1")/("abc1" + "abc2"), "date" -> {1/2,1/2}, "count" -> 4/9|>, 
  <|"cat" -> 1/2, "type" -> ("abc2")/("abc1" + "abc2"), "date" -> {1/2,1/2}, "count" -> 5/9|>}, 
 {"b", {2014, 1}} -> {<|"cat" -> 1, "type" -> 1,"date" -> {1, 1}, "count" -> 1|>}|>
```

Which is a mess.  It does calculate the correct share for each type (in the count key), but now I'd have to somehow pull this apart and put it back together properly.

Originally I didn't use associations, and did a lot of joining.  Using associations seems like a better idea but this level of complication is daunting.  I'm afraid that when I pull it apart and put it back together the pieces may not be in the same order.

Is there a better way to approach this?  Or, is there a reasonable way to simplify the result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start with a function `cost` that will tell us the total cost for each category/date pair.

```
cost[{cat_, date_}] := 100.
```

For illustration purposes, this function has been defined trivially -- the real cost function will have to look up its values somewhere.

**Using `Query`**

Let's define `total` to be a map from a category/date pair to the total count for that pair:

```
total = x1 // Query[GroupBy[{#cat, #date}&], Total, "count"]

(* <| {a,{2013,1}} -> 60
    , {a,{2014,1}} -> 90
    , {a,{2015,1}} -> 13
    , {b,{2013,1}} -> 135
    , {b,{2014,1}} -> 70
    |> *)
```

Now we can generate adjusted source data so that each entry has a new `cost` property containing the prorated cost of that entry:

```
x1 // Query[All, <| #, "cost" -> cost[{#cat, #date}] #count / total[{#cat, #date}] |>&]
```

[image: result screenshot]

**Without Using `Query`**

The previous section uses `Query`, but it does not depend upon any particularly advanced functionality.  We can perform the same operations without using `Query` at all:

```
total = GroupBy[x1, {#cat, #date}& -> (#count&), Total];

<| #, "cost" -> cost[{#cat, #date}] #count / total[{#cat, #date}] |>& /@ x1
(* same result as before *)
```

---

**Sidebar: How does the `Query` version work?**

Let's look at how `Query` is used above.  First:

```
x1 // Query[GroupBy[{#cat, #date}&], Total, "count"]
```

Queries specify an operator to apply to each element of each level of an expression.  The first operator is applied to level zero (the whole expression), the next to level one, etc.  Each level is acted upon twice: once while descending into the expression and a second time when ascending back out to top-level.  It is beyond the scope of this response to describe these phases in detail.  However, here is the sequence of events for this particular query:

1. *Level 0, descending* The `GroupBy` operator performs the necessary grouping and splits the original data into groups keyed by the `"cat"` and `"date"` keys.  `GroupBy` is documented as being a special operator in that it inserts a new level into the data that did not exist before.  While we started with a list of associations on level 0, after the grouping each level 1 element is a list of associations for a particular group.
2. *Level 1, descending* The `Total` operator is an ascending operator, so in a descending context it is treated as `All`, i.e. `Identity`.  This means that each group's list of associations will be left untouched as we descend.
3. *Level 2, descending* The `"count"` operator will extract the *count* property from each of the associations.  Thus, each association will be transformed into a count.  This is the last operator, so now we switch to the ascending phase.
4. *Level 2, ascending* The `"count"` operator is a descending operator, so it is treated as `All` in the ascending phase.  Each count undergoes no further transformation.
5. *Level 1, ascending* The `Total` operator now gets its chance to act since it is an ascending operator.  It is presented with a list of the counts generated by step 4, returning a single number representing the sum of those counts.
6. *Level 0, ascending* The `GroupBy` operator is a descending operator so it is treated as `All` in the ascending phase.  This means that association containing counts keyed by groups will be returned unchanged.  This association is the final result of the first query.

The second query is essentially of the form:

```
Query[All, f]
```

Short-cutting the description a bit, this applies the `All` operator to level 0 and the `f` operator to level 1.  Since `All` essentially means `Identity`, the query is equivalent to saying `Map[f]`.  In fact, we can see this by applying `Normal` to the query:

```
Query[All, f] // Normal
(* Map[f] *)
```

This `Normal` trick works for any query.

Tools described in [Visualizing Type System Operations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89080/142) can be helpful in developing an intuition for dataset and query operations.

Comment: This works well.  I had to make a small change since my "costs" are another association, so I had to do a preliminary `JoinAccross` to get them in a position for the mulitplication.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm very fuzzy on how Query works.  Could you expand upon how it's used  in you calculation of total?  Maybe break it down into pieces.  For example, could the same thing be accomplished without using Query?  I have read through the documentation but it's not helping me a whole lot.  I'm hoping for that "aha" moment.

Comment: I have added a non-query variant and a section describing how the query-based version works.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll mull over this the next time I have to deal with an `Association[]`.

Comment: All of that detail was extremely helpful - thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I am a relative novice with respect to manipulating `Association[]`/`Dataset[]` objects, so there might well be a better way than what I present below:

```
x1 = Dataset[x1];

treatData = Which[VectorQ[#, NumericQ], 100 Normalize[#, Total],
                  Length[#] == 1, First[#], True, #] &;

x1[GroupBy[{#cat &, #date &}], All][Values, Values,
   Merge[Composition[treatData, Union]]][Catenate,
   Map[KeyMap[# /. "count" -> "percentage" &]]]
```

[image: result]

Comment: Well, it works, but it's going to take me some time to understand it.  Thanks!

Comment: That you've said those words indicates to me that it can be expressed way better than I did. Wait for a bit, maybe someone more well-versed might come along.

Comment: I tried this on my actual data, which as you would imagine is much larger and not sorted the same way.  I found that it sorts type and percentage both according to their own values.  Thus the types no longer match the percentages.  You can see this if you reverse abc1 and abc2 in rows 1 & 3.  That is, abc1 will have count=30.  Even so, I learned a number of things from your solution which will help me to put something together that will work for my more complicated data.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes, I had exploited the fact that the data was almost, but not quite sorted. I'll have to think about the case you mention. In any event, I'm glad this was of some use.