# How to access Dataset's metadata

Tags: dataset, head

A `Dataset` object has internal metadata.  For example, let

```
ds = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>}];
```

Then, after re-formatting for legibility,

```
FullForm[ds]
```

shows this:

```
Dataset[
 List[
  Association[
   Rule["a",1],
   Rule["b","x"],
   Rule["c",List[1]]
  ]
 ],
 TypeSystem`Vector[
  TypeSystem`Struct[
   List["a","b","c"],
   List[
    TypeSystem`Atom[Integer],
    TypeSystem`Atom[String],
    TypeSystem`Vector[
     TypeSystem`Atom[Integer],
     1
    ]
   ]
  ],
  1
 ],
 Association[Rule["ID",204779820583110]]
]
```

One can't, however, access the parts of this expression in the usual way (i.e. using `Part`).  For example, `ds[[3]]` evaluates to

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also, one can't change the head of the `Dataset` object the usual way (i.e. using `Apply`):  `Head[List @@ ds]` evaluates to `Dataset`, not `List`.

---

**Questions:**

1. How can one access the internal parts of a `Dataset` object programmatically?
2. What other general *Mathematica* rules fail to hold when it comes to `Dataset` objects?
3. Where in the *Mathematica* documentation are the answers to the previous two questions to be found?

---

Comment: `ds` is `AtomQ`. Just try `AtomQ@ds`. `ds[[3]]` is like `(1/2)[[1]]`. (`FullForm[1/2]` is `Rational[1, 2]`).

Comment: There should be some useful functions for this job in ``Needs["TypeSystem`"]; Names["TypeSystem`*"]`` and ``Needs["Dataset`"]; Names["Dataset`*"]``. Most of these are probably undocumented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with the same `Dataset` as [m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) in [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115298/18476)

```
ds = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1/2}|>, 
              <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {"a", {}, 1/2}|>}]
```

The same information can be extracted using

```
Needs["Dataset`"] 
GetData@ds
GetRawData@ds
GetType@ds
ToDatasetHandle@ds
```

[image: dsInfo]

One can get all these information at once using

```
DatasetPart@ds
```

[image: DatasetPart@ds]

Comment: The `DatasetHandle` or `"ID"` is unique to each `Dataset`, therefore everyone will have a different one and it'll change after reevaluating the definition of `ds`.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I able to extract.

```
ds = 
  Dataset[
    {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1/2}|>, 
     <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {"a", {}, 1/2}|>}]
```

[image: ds]

```
{data, types, id} = 
  ToExpression[StringReplace[ToString @ FullForm[ds], "Dataset" -> "List"]];

Dataset[data]
```

[image: ds]

```
types
```

[image: types]

which has the raw input form

> ```
> TypeSystem`Vector[
>   TypeSystem`Struct[
>     {"a", "b", "c"}, 
>     {TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], TypeSystem`Atom[String], 
>       TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`AnyType, TypeSystem`AnyLength]}],
>   2]
> ```

```
id
```

> `<|"ID" -> 125700882739855|>`

I think it is interesting that code editor has special formatting for the type metadata.

Comment: The special formatting for the type metadata comes with a nice `Tooltip` and `CellPrint` after clicking feature.