# What's inside Dataset?

Tags: dataset

It seems that Dataset has rich structures in them, for example:

```
ds = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>}];

TreeForm[dataset]
```

[image]

Could you explain about this structure? In particular:

1. What is the ID for?
2. What are the varies `TypeSystem` for?

Comment: Some of the uses of `TypeSystem` by `Dataset` are discussed in [(87479)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87479/142) and [(89080)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89080/142).