# Composition with Transpose failure with Dataset

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, query

Is the failure of the 2nd Transpose here a known bug?

```
Dataset[{{0, 10}, {2, 11}, {3, 12}}][
 Transpose /* Map[MinMax] /* Transpose] // Normal
```

> ```
> Failure[Transpose, {"MessageTemplate" :> Transpose::nmtx, 
>   "MessageParameters" -> {{__}, Transpose}}]
> ```

Similarly for

```
Dataset[{{0, 10}, {2, 11}, {3, 12}}][
 Query[Transpose /* Map[MinMax]] /* Transpose]
```

For both of these, without the Normal, the error msg is: "The first two levels of {__} cannot be transposed".

Yet the seeming equivalent query, albeit with an intermediate Dataset, works:

```
Dataset[{{0, 10}, {2, 11}, {3, 12}}][Transpose /* Map[MinMax] ][
  Transpose]// Normal
```

And without Dataset, this works also:

```
{{0, 10}, {2, 11}, {3, 12}} // Transpose // Map[MinMax] // Transpose
```

> {{0, 10}, {3, 12}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to two factors:

1. The type system cannot infer the data type that results from a call to `MinMax`.
2. A type-checked application of the `Transpose` query operator will fail when applied to an argument with an unknown type (i.e. from `MinMax`).

I think that point #1 could be considered a bug, although the fact of the matter is that a great many operators are not (yet) known to the type system.  Given these omissions, it might be reasonable to expect the `Transpose` operator to be more forgiving.

**Analysis (current as of version 11.0.1)**

When an operation succeeds outside of a `Dataset` but fails within, the cause is usually a type-inferencing failure.  That is indeed the case here.

[traceTypes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89081/142) will reveal the failure:

```
traceTypes[Dataset[{{0, 10}, {2, 11}, {3, 12}}]][Transpose /* Map[MinMax] /* Transpose]
```

[image: traceTypes screenshot]

We can see that the type machinery cannot infer the resultant type of applying `MinMax` to a list of integers:

```
Needs["TypeSystem`"]
TypeApply[MinMax, {Vector[Atom[Integer], 3]}]
(* UnknownType *)
```

Furthermore, a type-checked application of `AssociationTranspose` (the query-form of `Transpose`) will not accept a vector of unknown type:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
TypeApply[AssociationTranspose, {Vector[UnknownType, 2]}]
(* FailureType[{Transpose, "nmtx"}, <|"Arguments" -> {__}|>] *)
```

This last failure is the source of the message we see.

**Work-around**

As noted in the question, a work-around is to perform the final `Transpose` in a second query:

```
Dataset[{{0, 10}, {2, 11}, {3, 12}}][Transpose /* Map[MinMax]][Transpose]
```

[image: double-query dataset screenshot]

When the final query result is wrapped back into a dataset, type *deduction* takes place which is more reliable than type *inferencing*.  By splitting our query in two, we allow such type deduction to take place so that the final `Transpose` operator can be applied to a known type:

```
Needs["Dataset`"]
Dataset[{{0, 10}, {2, 11}, {3, 12}}][Transpose /* Map[MinMax]] // GetType
(* Vector[Vector[Atom[Integer], 2], 2] *)

TypeApply[AssociationTranspose, {Vector[Vector[Atom[Integer], 2], 2]}]
(* Vector[Vector[Atom[Integer], 2], 2] *)
```

Comment: How come this is not an issue outside of Dataset? Is the type inference complexity worth it to basically give hints for formatting (and often the results are inconsistent anyway)?

Comment: The type system is only invoked within `Dataset`.  In v10.1, I [noted](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87479/142) that type information is used mainly for visualization and "sanity checking".  The situation seems largely unchanged in v11.0.1.  It would be nice if we could turn off the type-inferencing (and the sometimes flaky sanity checking) but retain the type-deduction (for visualization).  It will be interesting to see what happens to the type system after the [next-generation compiler](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?sx=compiler&c=423&v=1717) is released.

Answer (score 0):

If we change the last `Transpose` into a `f`,it will return a uncalculate structure

```
Dataset[{{0, 10}, {2, 11}, {3, 12}}][Transpose /* Map[MinMax] /* f]
```

> f[{{0, 3}, {10, 12}}]

But the `Transpose` doesn't work here,so I tend to consider it as a bug about `Dataset` operate

---

And the following operation is right in current rule

```
Dataset[{{0, 10}, {2, 11}, {3, 12}}][Transpose /* Map[MinMax], All]
```

http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2017-03-06-17-22-30.png